# How to read a Large JSON file using MPI using multiple processes. Where each process can read its chunk of file simultaneously

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parallel-processing, mpi

I have large JSON file, Its size is in Gigabytes. This files contains the data of tweets. I need to read this file using MPI for python multiple process in such a way that each process can read the file from its own portion simultaneously.

Currently what I am doing is diving the file in chunks by its size. But the problem is it corrupts my JSON data. As the file may be divided in such a way that it creates an Invalid JSON data.

How can I divide a file without disturbing by JSON objects inside.

Comment: Some piece of code is going to have to split your JSON file properly, i.e. respecting its internal structure - as you've already discovered just cutting it into quarters (or any other fraction) based on line or character counts is very likely to result in 4 (or n) broken JSON files.  You could pre-process the file, you could even have one process in the MPI program prepare the file for parallel reading.  Or you could say *stuff that for a game of soldiers* and give each process, in turn, sole access to the file to read its own chunk.  This way each process sees a valid JSON file.